# AppendTo Div in SweetAlert with DataTable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I am currently using SweetAlert to populate a dialog to allow the user to select multiple rows in a table and then save to the DB using an ajax request mapped to a controller via MVC Core.

However, I am unable to get the DataTable to populate in the view before it pops up. What is the best way to get this working?

Here is my SweetAlert call that triggers the popup with the TableView:

```
$('#ApplicationTable').on('change', '#enableApp', function (event) {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("EnableApplication")',
                    data: {
                        'AppId': this.value, 'UserId': @Model.Id },
                    type: "post",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (status) {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Permissions',
                            content: {
                                element: 'div',
                                attributes: {
                                    id: 'searchTableWrapPermissions'
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        swal("Error enabling app, please contact support.");
                    }
                });
```

The idea is to create the popup with a div that I can then append the table to the id being placed in the content.

OnDeviceReady I also call this:

```
 $('<table id="PermissionsTable" class="searchTable table table-striped stripe row-border dataTable">< thead ><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead ></table >').appendTo('#searchTableWrapPermissions');
```

This seems to me it would work logically but for some reason I am unable to get it to popup with the sweetalert view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Ajax, you can use a JsonResult as return type from the controller (not a partialView) this way you are not depending on the razorengine, Instead you would append your data to that div with JQuery or plain JavaScript using that returned json from the controller. This also gives you more control in you frontend.

Answer (score 0):

MVC POP UP:
1.Step 1:Create a Shared Page

> _help1.cshtml

```
@model string
<script>

    $("#helpDIV").ready(function () {
        $('#helpmnu').dataTable({ "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]] });
    });
    $("#wrapper").draggable({ cursor: "move" });


    document.onkeyup = CloseHelp;
    function CloseHelp()
    {
        var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
        if (KeyID == 27)
        {
            $('#helpDIV').html("");
        }
        else if(KeyID==undefined)
        {
            $('#helpDIV').html("");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    function HelpRowClick(id) {
        var field = $('#ReferanceFieldID').val().split('/');
        var columnnm = $('#ReferanceColumn').val().split('/');
        var row = document.getElementById(id);
        for (var i = 0; i <= field.length - 1; i++) {
            var col = document.getElementById("helpmnu").rows[row.rowIndex].cells[columnnm[i]].innerHTML;
            $("#" + field[i]).val(col);
            if (i == 0) {
                $("#" + field[i]).focus();
            }
        }
        $('#helpDIV').html("");
    }

</script>
<script>
    function imgpreview(id)
    {
        var w = 500;
        var h = 200;
        var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
        var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

        width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
        height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

        if (screen.width <= 768)
        {
            w = 10;
            h = 10;
        }
        var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
        var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

        var ctrlimg = document.getElementById(id).src;
        txtCode = "<HTML><HEAD>"
        + "</HEAD><BODY TOPMARGIN=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 style='background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56)'><CENTER>"
        + "<IMG src='" + ctrlimg + "' BORDER=0 NAME=FullImage  "
        + "onload='window.resizeTo(document.FullImage.width,document.FullImage.height)'>"
        + "</CENTER>"
        + "</BODY></HTML>";
        mywindow = window.open('', 'image', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menuBar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        mywindow.document.open();
        mywindow.document.write(txtCode);
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #textarea {
        border: none;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: cornsilk;
    }

    #wrapper {
        background-color: white;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 231, 43, 0.00);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 350px;
        height: 420px;
    }

    #helpDIV {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 30em;
        height: 18em;
        margin-top: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
        margin-left: -13em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" id="ReferanceFieldID" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ReferanceColumn" value="" />
    <div style="height:30px;width:100%;background-color:#27658a;vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold">
        <table id="tableHeader" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="3px" cellspacing="3px">
            <tr>
                @*Take a refresh button*@


                <td align="center" style="width:80%;color:#eee;text-align:center"> </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:10%;color: darkorange;">
                    <span title="Refresh" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="color:red;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;"></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:10%">
                    <span title="Close" onclick="CloseHelp();" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" style="color:red;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="textarea" style="padding:5px; font-size:11px">
        @(new HtmlString(Model))
    </div>
</div>
```

2>Step 2: download datatable.js 
[enter link description here](https://www.datatables.net/download/index)

and link with main cshtml page
3>step 3:Views page( cshtml page)

> cshtml page:
>   Place  the codes:

```
<head>
function GetHelp(urlstring, id, colnm, caption) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: path of controller page function,
            success: function (result) {              
                $('#ReferanceFieldID').val(id);
                $('#ReferanceColumn').val(colnm);                
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#WaitingMode").hide();
                msgError("Error: " + textStatus + "," + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</head>
      <body>
 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M_WEEK.COMPCD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control textbox_image", id = "COMPCD", @placeholder = "COMPCD", maxlength = 4 } })
                        <img src="~/Image/search.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="Help_image_button" title="Help" onclick="GetHelp('@Url.Action("GetCompanyDetails", PageControllerName)','COMPCD/COMPNM','1/0','Company Code')" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M_COMP.COMPNM, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "COMPNM", @TabIndex = -1, @placeholder = "COMPNM", maxlength = 60, @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="helpDIV">  
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
```

4>Step 4:

> Controller page

```
public string PRODGRPCD_help(ImprovarDB DB)
    {
        var query = (from c in DB.M_PRODGRP
                     join i in DB.M_CNTRL_HDR on c.M_AUTONO equals i.M_AUTONO
                     where i.INACTIVE_TAG == "N"
                     select new
                     {
                         code = c.PRODGRPCD,
                         name = c.PRODGRPNM,
                     }).ToList();
        System.Text.StringBuilder SB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        SB.Append("<table id='helpmnu' class='table-hover' cellpadding='3px' cellspacing='3px' width='100%'><thead style='background-color:#2965aa; color:white'><tr>");
        SB.Append("<th>Product Group Name</th><th>Product Group Code</th></tr></thead>");
        SB.Append("<tbody>");
        for (int i = 0; i <= query.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            SB.Append("<tr id='Hrow_" + i.ToString() + "' onclick='HelpRowClick(this.id)'><td>" + query[i].name + "</td><td>" + query[i].code + "</td></tr>");
        }
        SB.Append("</tbody></table>");
        return SB.ToString();
    }

 return PartialView("_Help1", PRODGRPCD_help(DB));
```

Here I am use LINQ query u can use 
normal query

```
query = (from c in DB.M_PRODGRP
                         join i in DB.M_CNTRL_HDR on c.M_AUTONO equals i.M_AUTONO
                         where i.INACTIVE_TAG == "N"
                         select new
                         {
                             code = c.PRODGRPCD,
                             name = c.PRODGRPNM,
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: are you saying there is no way to utilize Sweet Alerts for this functionality? We use this throughout our whole site right now so we don't want to be switching between alert modals.

Comment: Mr. Hook, I was able to get this populated but unfortunately am unable to accept your answer because it does not answer my question. I am not looking for an MVC Core PopUP Approach. If you read my question closely you will see I am looking for a solution that uses SweetAlert to fire these requests via AJAX. I will be posting my solution soon in hopes it helps someone else with this question in the future.

Comment: Also in your CSHTML your calling Javascript in the head and wanted to mention this is very poor practice. The DOM has yet to be established and any use of JQuery will most likely return undefined. By moving this logic to the end of your page in a <script> tag you will yield better results. When I post my full solution, I will also post some extended info to help with resources as to why that is better. :)

Comment: This will help to open pop up.Here I have use datatable for enhance filtering technique.It is not sweet alert.

Answer (score 0):

Do one things make dynamic html for data table and in success function of ajax call call swalplugin.

```
var htmlcontent ="<table></table>"
 swal({
     title: "what ever",
     text: htmlcontent,
     html: true
 });
```